# How to fetch value from session storage and use it in handler function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Session storage set item value is cannot be passed into ready function to perform other operations using if condition:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Re() {
            sessionStorage.setItem("hasClick", true);
            window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test");
        }

        function ready(callback) {

            if (document.readyState != 'loading') callback();

            else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);

            else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function () {
                if (document.readyState == 'complete') callback();
            });
        }

        ready(function () {
            console.log("It worked!");
            var hasClick = localStorage.getItem("hasClick");
            if (hasClick == true) {
                var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
                labels[4].style.cssText = 'color:blue; font-size:22px;';
            }
        });
    </script>

   var hasClick = localStorage.getItem("hasClick");
```

Value is not passed to hasClick

Comment: I don't see function `Re` being called. Is there more related script which you haven't mentioned in the question

Comment: It is being called using a onclick html input tag.

Comment: `sessionStorage` !== `localStorage`